# can we call a java method by js?

Tags: java, javascript

In my Java Script , I want to call a java method . Is it possible to call a java method by js w/o using ajax?

Comment: Where is the Java? Running on the server (e.g. JSP) or the client (e.g. applet)?

Answer (score 4):

use Direct Web Remoting for your Javascript to Java Interaction

> DWR is a Java library that enables
>   Java on the server and JavaScript in a
>   browser to interact and call each
>   other as simply as possible.
>
> DWR is Easy Ajax for Java

[Examples](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/examples/index.html)

EDIT:
as Daniel said u can use Rhino interpreter or run an applet to do the call

If you're running from  a browser then there is a sandbox which has a security policy that defines and disallows calling Java Methods directly from browser.

Comment: 'without AJAX' ? I'm not sure about the OP's motivation not to use JS, so you may want to address that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running in Rhino javascript, which is a JS engine implemented in the JVM, then yes.

If you're running a browser, the answer is almost certainly no, at least directly. You could write a Java applet to run in the browser, and you might be able [to call methods in it from JavaScript](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/js_java.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly call Java method in javascript irrespective of Ajax present or not. Javascript is at client side.

If you are using JSP, then you can call using scriplets

```
<script>
   ....
   if(somecondition) {
     <%
          ClassXXX.xXXX();
     %>
   }
   ....
</script>
```

Comment: I think we need to specify the Class Name with this

Comment: although It calls scriplet(<% %>) code first whenever i load the page.

Comment: @saloni Yes you are right it will call on load and only once. we can't interact between JS and Java directly

Comment: your answer is premised on the assumption that there is no client-side (i.e. browser resident) Java.  This is not necessarily true.